# how to dynamically load a scala template

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I Wonder if there is any anyway of loading a template dynamically using playframework2 and scala using reflection. In play 1.x i used to do something like following:

```
   public static void template(String templateName) {
    renderTemplate("templateName");
}
```

Is there anyway i can achieve the same thing using play2.x?

Java example/solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can get the template object via reflection and then call its apply method using structural types.

```
val c = Class.forName(fullyQualifiedTemplateClassName + "$")
val template = c.getField("MODULE$").get(c).asInstanceOf[{def apply():Html}]

Ok(template())
```